# Oracle Forms 10g ActiveX controls

Tags: oracle, activex, oracleforms

I can't find much documentation on this and I haven't worked with `Forms` before. As I understand it, `Forms 10` **doesn't support** `ActiveX` controls any longer.

Does that mean the controls won't work at all in `WebForms` or that Oracle just doesn't handle bugs on this issue any longer? Has anyone tried using `ActiveX` controls in `Forms 10` and succeded? Can the controls be somehow wrapped in `Java` and work?

If it helps, I'm seeking to build an `ActiveX` control to communicate with hardware devices such as *scanner and a photo camera*, take pictures, process the images and then return them to a `WebForms` running server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right using Active X and Oracle Forms when deployed on the web is not supported by Oracle.

Oracle recommend the use of Pluggable Java Components instead. The following paragraph is taken from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/formsservicesfaq-084838.html)

> **I currently have a client-server application that uses an embedded**
>   **ActiveX control to communicate with an external device.  How can I**
>   **maintain this functionality when I deploy the application on the Web?**
>
> Assuming that the device in question (for example, a Scanner) is
>   attached to each client machine, rather than the server, you will use
>   a Pluggable Java Component (PJC) to extend the capabilities of the
>   Forms Java Client and allow it to talk to the hardware in question. 
>   JDeveloper 3.2 provides a Wizard to help you build such pluggable Java
>   Components.

Whether your Active X control will work or not, unfortunately the answer is that it might or it might not. If not you are on your own.

I agree that documentation is hard to find. The best place to start is the [Forms Page on OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/index.html) Followed by the [Forms 10g technical listings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/techlisting10g-085500.html) and the even older [9i and earlier](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/techlisting-084882.html) docs.

Comment: I've seen the official statement on the Oracle website, but my question was whether someone tried using ActiveX on Forms 10 or higher and worked. I've already been through part of teh documentation without reaching any conclusion.

Comment: That's not what your question said. It said "Does that mean the controls won't work at all in WebForms or that Oracle just doesn't handle bugs on this issue any longer?" Perhaps you can edit it to make it clearer?